# Sample from an existing df in between values within two fields

Tags: r

Here are 2 data frames:

```
predictions_df <- structure(list(x = 1:12, prediction = c(0.625017376747316, 0.466366204403752, 
0.37483244060349, 0.322022052935517, 0.29155310978436, 0.273974058810806, 
0.263831828684945, 0.257980270936994, 0.254604215803884, 0.252656401435002, 
0.251532610304219, 0.250884239224406), prediction_lower_ci = c(0.637121135070348, 
0.481665521232155, 0.388315112420773, 0.33225860464922, 0.298596919568747, 
0.278383226502553, 0.266244993184834, 0.258956037742953, 0.254579052225944, 
0.251950691774454, 0.25037237294381, 0.249424599464052), prediction_upper_ci = c(0.613421389646899, 
0.452345737567938, 0.363057108714167, 0.313561985523989, 0.286125488278378, 
0.270916689257592, 0.262486036992328, 0.257812696413583, 0.255222136219927, 
0.253786118021837, 0.25299009395326, 0.252548836092743)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

example_data <- structure(list(cohort_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L), x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -144L))
```

The two data frames look like this:

```
predictions_df
    x prediction prediction_lower_ci prediction_upper_ci
1   1  0.6250174           0.6371211           0.6134214
2   2  0.4663662           0.4816655           0.4523457
3   3  0.3748324           0.3883151           0.3630571
4   4  0.3220221           0.3322586           0.3135620
5   5  0.2915531           0.2985969           0.2861255
6   6  0.2739741           0.2783832           0.2709167
7   7  0.2638318           0.2662450           0.2624860
8   8  0.2579803           0.2589560           0.2578127
9   9  0.2546042           0.2545791           0.2552221
10 10  0.2526564           0.2519507           0.2537861
11 11  0.2515326           0.2503724           0.2529901
12 12  0.2508842           0.2494246           0.2525488

example_data |> glimpse()
Rows: 144
Columns: 2
$ cohort_id <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2…
$ x         <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5…
```

I would like to mutate a new column `sample_pred` onto example_data such that each value of x corresponds to the corresponding row in predictions_df. The mean for each x should be `prediction` and the values should fluctuate between `prediction_lower_ci` and `prediction_upper_ci`.

For example, the first row in example_data has an x value of 1. I would like a new value `sample_pred` between 0.6371211 and 0.6134214. The second row has a x value of 2, I would like `sample_pred` to be between 0.4816655 and 0.4523457.

Once complete if I do `example_data |> filter(x == 1) |> pull(sample_pred) |> mean()` I would like the value to be close to 0.6250174. For x == 2 I would like the mean to be close to 0.4663662. Etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you want the samples to be drawn. For a uniform distribution between the upper and lower bounds you could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

result <- example_data |>
  mutate(lower = predictions_df$prediction_lower_ci[match(x, predictions_df$x)],
         upper = predictions_df$prediction_upper_ci[match(x, predictions_df$x)]
         ) |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(sample_pred = runif(1, pmin(lower, upper), pmax(lower, upper))) |>
  select(-lower, -upper)
```

This gives you samples that lie strictly between the upper and lower confidence intervals,

```r
result
#> # A tibble: 144 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    cohort_id     x sample_pred
#>        <int> <int>       <dbl>
#>  1         1     1       0.637
#>  2         1     2       0.470
#>  3         1     3       0.375
#>  4         1     4       0.332
#>  5         1     5       0.297
#>  6         1     6       0.271
#>  7         1     7       0.265
#>  8         1     8       0.258
#>  9         1     9       0.255
#> 10         1    10       0.252
#> # ... with 134 more rows
```

As we can see, the mean predictions for each `x` value are close to the predicted values:

```r
result |> group_by(x) |> summarize(sample_pred = mean(sample_pred))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>        x sample_pred
#>    <int>       <dbl>
#>  1     1       0.625
#>  2     2       0.465
#>  3     3       0.375
#>  4     4       0.321
#>  5     5       0.295
#>  6     6       0.275
#>  7     7       0.264
#>  8     8       0.258
#>  9     9       0.255
#> 10    10       0.253
#> 11    11       0.252
#> 12    12       0.251
```

However, it may be better to have the samples follow a normal distribution. Although this means that a small number of samples might fall outside of the upper and lower confidence intervals, this is as we should expect. It also means that the means and calculated confidence intervals for the samples should closely match those of the predictions:

```r
result <- example_data |>
  mutate(lower = predictions_df$prediction_lower_ci[match(x, predictions_df$x)],
         upper = predictions_df$prediction_upper_ci[match(x, predictions_df$x)],
         preds = predictions_df$prediction[match(x, predictions_df$x)],
         sd = abs(upper - preds)/1.96,
         sample_pred = rnorm(n(), preds, sd)) |>
  select(-upper, -lower)
```

Giving us

```
result
#> # A tibble: 144 x 5
#>    cohort_id     x preds        sd sample_pred
#>        <int> <int> <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1         1     1 0.625 0.00592         0.636
#>  2         1     2 0.466 0.00715         0.456
#>  3         1     3 0.375 0.00601         0.386
#>  4         1     4 0.322 0.00432         0.322
#>  5         1     5 0.292 0.00277         0.290
#>  6         1     6 0.274 0.00156         0.275
#>  7         1     7 0.264 0.000687        0.264
#>  8         1     8 0.258 0.0000855       0.258
#>  9         1     9 0.255 0.000315        0.255
#> 10         1    10 0.253 0.000576        0.252
#> # ... with 134 more rows
```

And

```r
result |> group_by(x) |> summarize(sample_pred = mean(sample_pred))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>        x sample_pred
#>    <int>       <dbl>
#>  1     1       0.622
#>  2     2       0.467
#>  3     3       0.374
#>  4     4       0.323
#>  5     5       0.290
#>  6     6       0.274
#>  7     7       0.264
#>  8     8       0.258
#>  9     9       0.255
#> 10    10       0.253
#> 11    11       0.251
#> 12    12       0.250
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Can I ask a follow up on `sd = abs(upper - preds)/1.96`. Why do this? The residual / a 95% ci? It's not clicking :/

Comment: The `abs` here is just because you seem to have the upper and lower confidence intervals round the wrong way. But essentially, I'm assuming your `ci` columns represent the 95% confidence intervals around the predictions. Since an upper 95% CI is 1.96 standard deviations above the mean, then if we take the difference between the upper limit and mean, then divide that result by 1.96, we get the value `sd`. This value, when plugged into the `sd` argument of `rnorm`, with `mean` set to the prediction value, will generate a random number with 95% probability of falling inside the confidence limits

Comment: "Since an upper 95% CI is 1.96 standard deviations above the mean, then if we take the difference between the upper limit and mean, then divide that result by 1.96, we get the value sd". Makes complete sense. Thanks!